# <a href> will not open links when the path has spaces. (kml)

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am using google earth to map placemarkers that each display their attributes. Some of the attributes are hyperlinks that open up a file or folder. When I use a-href to link a folder path that includes spaces, the link will not work in Google Earth. Is there a way to make the link work without changing the folder name?

Comment: I think you could show us the KML markup @tanaydin is probably correct about the escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

While printing href attribute, you have to escape it for html special characters. So your spaces will be %20.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Clicking the link still does nothing and when i copy and paste the link it has the %20 inside of it as part of the folder path